# How to echo array values which are incremented PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, increment

I have an array like this:

```
$aArray = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 0, 'three' =>0);
```

And a while loop like this:

```
$x = 50;
$y = 400;

$current = current($aArray);

while ($x<$y) {
    $current++;
    $x+=50;

    if($x==$y) {
        $current = next($aArray);
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to show the array with the total times incrementation, but I don't know how. And is it able to show it without using a loop?

Comment: So you want to know how many times the loop was executed?

Comment: I don't understand what is your expected outpout. Do you want to print the resulting array at the end of the whole operation?

Comment: do you want to Count the number of Increment occurred during array formation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the keys of the array and then run according to index.

Consider the following modification:

```
$aArray = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 0, 'three' =>0);
$keys = array_keys($aArray);

$x = 50;
$y = 400;

$i = 0;
while ($x<$y) {
    $aArray[$keys[$i]]++;
    $x+=50;

    if($x==$y) {
        $i++;
    }
}

print_r($aArray); // array('one' => 7, 'two' => 0, 'three' =>0);
```

If you don't want to loop you can just do:

```
$delta = $y - $x;
$cnt = intval($delta / 50);
if ($delta % 50 != 0)
    $cnt++
```

Now `$cnt` will be 7 and you can set it in: `$aArray["one"] = $cnt;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count the number of array incremented I have added a some line of coding

```js
$x = 50;
$y = 400;
$aArray = array('one' => 0, 'two' => 0, 'three' =>0);
$countInc=0;

$current = current($aArray);

while ($x<$y) {
    $current++;
    $x+=50;
    $countInc++;
  
    if($x==$y) {
        $current = next($aArray);
    }
}
echo "Total Number of Increment from that Array: ". $countInc;
```

Comment: The output I got , Total Number of Increment from that Array: 7